# Incomprehensible NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I have a very basic program, that is supposed to display a label and a text field. I am able to display the text. For the textfield, I can create it without error, but when I add it to the stage and run the program I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField.draw(TextField.java:301)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawChildren(Group.java:111)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:58)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.draw(Stage.java:128)
at com.pace.converter.MainMenuScreen.render(MainMenuScreen.java:52)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.pace.converter.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

As I don't know how to put line numbers in the code block of my comments, here are the lines pointed by the error :

MainMenuScreen.java: 52 is

```
stage.draw();
```

MyGdxGame.java: 21 is

```
super.render();
```

I don't understand why I have this NullPointerException as I created the TextField before adding it to the stage.
And here is my complete code :

Main activity :

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    AssetManager assets;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        assets = new AssetManager();

        this.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }

    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Main menu screen :

```
public MainMenuScreen(final MyGdxGame gam) {
    game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"));
    stage = new Stage();

    labelStyle = new LabelStyle(game.assets.get("font1.ttf", BitmapFont.class), Color.WHITE);
    labelTest = new Label("Test", labelStyle);
    textFieldTest = new TextField("Test", skin);

    stage.addActor(labelTest);
    stage.addActor(textFieldTest);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.281f, 0.602f, 0.844f, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: why not debug into the problem or get the sourcejar or the disassembled code of the library file in question and look into the problem?  you don't even tell us the version of libgdx you are using, so relating your line numbers with the actual code is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all you need to check some things which could be `null`.. wrap your code in `try-catch` blocks
I don't know what is `stage` but check if it has been initialized or not ?

If `stage` is not `null`
then check in your `Main menu Screen`

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json")); // is the skin null ? if the file 'skin.json' couldn't be found then this would be null.. check this

textFieldTest = new TextField("Test", skin); // If skin is null, you're adding it here
```

as for the `super.render();` is it even supposed to be called here ?